# Eclipse C++ not building .txt files in debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I have a C++ project that reads information from .txt files. Everything has been running properly when I debug in Eclipse but when I run the application outside of eclipse using the debug .exe it can't find the text files. This is because Eclipse isn't building the text files in the debug folder (Not sure why it runs when I debug inside of eclipse then).

I have a folder in my project that contains all my text files and that entire folder isn't being built in the /Debug folder. I've had a look around some file properties and options like "Exclude from build" haven't been ticked. I've no idea where else to check.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ compilers don't interact with `.txt` files, those files are loaded dynamically during 
run time.

I believe your issue is that your putting the file name in your executable relative to where the program is running. That can be an issue as your program could run in different location when eclipse launches it.

Example:

```
Project File
    Bin
          Executable.exe
    Program.cpp
    text.txt
```

If you have this type of structure, and you run your program through tool it might make the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) set to `Project File` and so the relative path to text file would be `text.txt`. But if you were to launch the program from inside the `bin` file than the relative path to the text file would be `..\text.txt`

An ease solution to this is to place the `text.txt` file in both the `bin` file and the `project file` or don't use `relative path` but use `absoulte path`

`Absoulte path` is when you write down the path starting from the  root like so `C:\Project File\text.txt`

Comment: Thanks! It's working perfectly now.

I added some code so that if it fails to open from the location that is passed to it then it will add "..//" before the path and try again.